# Linux server wont shutdown - A start job is running for Login iSCSI Target

Tags: centos7, iscsi, dracut

I am settin up a server with draut and iSCSI - I messed up a target / IP mapping, and now my server is stuck while booting:

> A start job is running for Login iSCSI Target ... (23min 10s / no limit)

I am currently unable to even reboot the server to edit the kernal arguments, pressing Control+Alt+Delete seems to have started the shutdown process, but the server is still hun waiting on this job with seemingly no timeout.

Having only KVM access to this node, how can I force a shutdown without having to physically hold the power button? How can I enforce time limits on jobs so I dont get stuck in this situation again?

Comment: You'll have to go hit the reset button, or have remote hands do it.

Comment: If I can get hands on it - how can I set job timeouts to be sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Which Linux distribution is this? Which service is being started here?

Comment: CentOS 7, iSCSI Login, whichever service that is.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I can't find a systemd unit with that particular description on CentOS 7. Did you do something nonstandard in setting this up?